# creating a string by mixing char[]s and ints in C

Tags: c, string, formatting, scanf

I am new to C and I am trying to figure out how to create separate strings (char[]) made up of a mix of char[]s and ints that line up in length-

for example if I have char[] first name, char[] last name and int age I need them all on 1 line the same length example -

Joe     |smith  |45 
Amy    |Footh  |2

with each line being its own char[] and lining up.

This is the code I have so far -

```
while(temp != NULL)
{
    char listLine[IDLEN + FOODNAMELEN + DESCLEN + 10];
    char * id = temp->data->id;
    char * name = temp->data->name;
    int dollars = temp->data->price.dollars;
    int cents = temp->data->price.cents;

    sprintf(listLine,"%s |%s |$%d.%d\n", id, name, dollars, cents);
    printf("%s",listLine);
    temp = temp->next;
}
```

This works OK but I cant seem to line up the | with each other.

Im still new to stack exchange, so I am not sure how to mark as homework... but yes this is homework.

any help would be great.

Thanks

Comment: Use   **sprintf("%10s%10s...**  and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use width specifiers with the `printf` format specifiers.

Example:

`printf("%3d | %10s", 32, "Hello");`

will print

_32 | _____Hello

where `_`(underscore) represents a space

You can also specify width as an argument using `printf("%*d", width, 32);`. The `width` can be determined by the length of strings you are printing. The maximum length of a string can be your desired width. For numbers you can assume no number (32-bit number) will be greater than 10 digits (2<sup>32</sup> has 10 digits in decimal notation)

See [this](http://beej.us/guide/bgc/output/html/multipage/printf.html)

Comment: Thanks for the help, but if I have some names that are 5 chars and some that are 3 it will not line up. I will be printing from an array of different names so it has to be responsive. Sorry I hope this makes some sense.

Comment: Thank you very much! That is a huge help!

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to line these up on the pipe characters ('|'), then you could make a first pass on your data to determine the maximum length of each field in characters, and then on the second pass, space-pad each field that is shorter than it's maximum so that when all have been formatted, each field will be exactly the same length.

Or, you could determine the max length you want for each field and then format those using a printf() statement.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you're wanting to add tabs? You can add tabs by adding \t

```
"%s \t|%s \t|$%d.%d\n"
```